# Can we add our own entities (special characters) like "&aacute;" and "&oelig;" using XML Schema (XSD)?

Tags: xml, xsd, special-characters, dtd

DTD has the customisation where you can add these special characters so they are legal. Can the same be done with XML Schema? My research shows XML Schema does not support Entities, hence Entities are enabled through an Internal DTD Subset. Is this true? And does this mean I can use Schema but will also need a DTD to define the special characters?

Comment: Hello Katie, welcome to StackOverflow. I see that it is your first question. Can you add new-line characters between your line so that your text is more readable ? To define a new line, you must add an empty line or terminate your sentence with <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, named entities can only be declared using a DTD; this functionality is not available through XSD. XSD is all about validation.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for your comment. Essentially, I have been asked to do some research regarding this. Typically, we use DTDs because we can add our own entities like "&aacute;" and "&oelig;" and that's the customisation we need due to the texts we are transcribing. However, there are questions about whether we should start using RELAX NG. Are you saying that if this is the customisation we need, that we should stick to using a DTD. I wasn't sure if you meant correct as in that, or that it is possible to use XSD, and a DTD for solely for the purpose of special characters.

Comment: To declare entities you need a DTD. To do validation you have a range of options: DTDs, XSD, Relax NG, schematron.